# Inserção 1 para muitos está gravando dois registros no banco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migrations

Tenho as seguintes classes: `Usuario`, `Noticia`, `Bloco` e `Editoria`.

Eu tinha um relacionamento `One to Many` entre as tabelas `Noticia` e `Editoria`, `Noticia` e `Bloco`.

Funciona perfeitamente, ao colocar o mesmo relacionamento entre `Noticia` e `Usuario` ao gravar uma notícia no banco grava junto um novo usuário idêntico ao que está fazendo a operação!

Segue abaixo código das `Classes` e do `Controller`:

```
[Table("Editoria")]
public class Editoria
{
    [Key]
    public int EditoriaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Noticia> Noticias { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bloco")]
public class Bloco
{
    [Key]
    public int BlocoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Noticia> Noticias { get; set; }
}

[Table("Usuario")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("UserNameExists", "Usuario")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Senha { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Rg { get; set; }

    public string Cpf { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Cadastro")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Noticia> Noticias { get; set; }
}

public class Noticia
{
    [Key]
    public int NoticiaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Título")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O título da notícia e obrigatório!")]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 20, ErrorMessage = "O Título deve ter no máximo 200 e no mínimo 20 caractéres!")]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Resumo")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [StringLength(180, MinimumLength = 20, ErrorMessage = "O Resumo deve ter no máximo 180 e no mínimo 20 caractéres!")]
    public string Resumo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Chapéu")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O Chapéu deve ter no máximo 30 e no mínimo 5 caractéres!")]
    public string Chapeu { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Foto de capa")]
    public string UrlFotoCapa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conteúdo da Notícia")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O conteúdo da notícia e obrigatório!")]
    public string Texto { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Data Publicação")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Atualização")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fonte da Notícia")]
    public string TituloFonte { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço da Fonte")]
    public string UrlFonte { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Visualizações")]
    public int? ViewNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome do Entrevistado")]
    public string NomeEntrevistado { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "Hora")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{hh\:mm\:ss}")]
    public TimeSpan Hora { get; set; }

    public string ImageResizerType { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Bloco")]
    public virtual int BlocoId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Bloco")]
    public virtual Bloco Bloco { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Editoria")]
    public virtual int EditoriaId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Editoria")]
    public virtual Editoria Editoria { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Código do `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(InsertEditNoticiaViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var noticia = model.Noticia;

        var blocos = _context.Blocos.ToList();

        foreach (var item in blocos)
        {
            item.Nome = item.Nome.Replace("_", " ");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Editorias = new SelectList(_context.Editorias.ToList(), "EditoriaId", "Nome", model.EditoriaSelect);
            model.Blocos = new SelectList(blocos, "BlocoId", "Nome", model.BlocoSelect);
            return View(model);
        }

        if (model.FotoBase == null)
        {
            noticia.UrlFotoCapa = "/Content/img/img-padrao.png";
        }
        else
        {
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(model.FotoBase.FileName);
            var foto = string.Concat(DateTime.Now, ext).Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "-").Replace(" ", "-");
            const string localpath = "/Upload/Noticias/Capa/";
            var localFisicoImagem = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(localpath), Path.GetFileName(foto));
            model.FotoBase.SaveAs(localFisicoImagem);

            var img = Image.FromStream(model.FotoBase.InputStream, true, true);
            var w = img.Width;
            var h = img.Height;

            model.Noticia.ImageResizerType = w > h ? "crop" : "max";
            model.Noticia.UrlFotoCapa = localpath + foto;
        }

        var editoria = _context.Editorias.Find(model.EditoriaSelect);
        noticia.Editoria = editoria;

        var user = UserRepo.GetLogedUser();

        noticia.User = user;

        var bloco = _context.Blocos.Find(model.BlocoSelect);
        noticia.Bloco = bloco;

        noticia.DataPublicacao = noticia.DataPublicacao.Add(model.Noticia.Hora);
        noticia.DataAtualizacao = noticia.DataPublicacao;
        noticia.Status = false;

        _context.Noticias.Add(noticia);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var log = new Log
        {
            Action = "CREATE",
            NoticiaId = noticia.NoticiaId,
            UserId = noticia.User.UserId,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            UpdateDate = DateTime.Now,
            OriginalValues = js.Serialize(noticia.Texto),
            NewValues = null
        };

        _context.Logs.Add(log);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception  e)
    {
        var blocos = _context.Blocos.ToList();

        foreach (var item in blocos)
        {
            item.Nome = item.Nome.Replace("_", " ");
        }

        model.Editorias = new SelectList(_context.Editorias.ToList(), "EditoriaId", "Nome", model.EditoriaSelect);
        model.Blocos = new SelectList(blocos, "BlocoId", "Nome", model.BlocoSelect);
        var error = e.Message;
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Estou fazendo exatamente como a `Editoria` e o `Bloco` porém não da certo!

Comment: Em vez de `noticia.User = user;` não deveria ser `noticia.UserId = userId;`?

Comment: @ramaral Não. Isto faria com que o Entity Framework inserisse mais um registro de usuário, porque a informação não está sendo observada pelo contexto.

Comment: @HermesAutran Você poderia colocar na sua pergunta o código do seguinte método: `UserRepo.GetLogedUser();`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Posso não estar a ver bem, mas aquilo que quero dizer é que a [ForeignKey("User")] não está a ser setada, além de `noticia.User = user;` seria necessário também `noticia.UserId = noticia.User.UserId;`

Comment: Encontrei o problema, porém não sei o porque ele acontece, vou postar como resposta para quem tiver o mesmo problema posteriormente!

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o problema, não sei porque ele acontece mas vou postar como resolvi para caso alguém venha a ter o mesmo problema posteriormente.

Na seguinte linha:

```
var user = UserRepo.GetLogedUser();

noticia.User = user;
```

Esse método estático `GetLogedUser()` simplesmente faz uma pesquisa no banco pegando o usuário que está logado no momento, segue o código abaixo:

```
public static User GetLogedUser()
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return null;

    var login = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    var context = new NewsContext();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Login == login && u.Status);
    return user;
}
```

Porém não sei porque motivo o quando atribuo esse `Objeto` a `notícia` ao salvar ele da um `SaveChanges()` no `Usuario` também.

Mas quando eu faço da seguinte maneira:

```
var user = UserRepo.GetLogedUser();
noticia.User = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);
```

E gravado apenas o `ID` do `usuário` e não um novo registro no banco.

Comment: Isto porque, no comando correto, você está pedindo para o contexto que salvará o registro da notícia observar também o usuário, o que possivelmente não estava acontecendo ao utilizar `UserRepo.GetLogedUser();`. Mesmo que o usuário estivesse correto no retorno do método estático, o contexto entenderia que seria um novo usuário.